# What can be done about an external command run from powershell run by Start-Job that doesn't have a silent option?

Tags: powershell, putty

I'm trying to run plink in a Start-Job manner, but plink always prompts you asking if you want to store the key in the registery when connecting to a new machine....or one that it doesn't recognize as that machine; so is there a way to listen for a state change on the job, and bring it back into the foreground to answer `y` so that it's added, or to just tell it to answer 'y' when prompted?

Comment: So, you want to take the protection that is given by not automatically trusting any random machine and bypass it? Isn't the usual advice to always initiate the first connections manually so that you *can* make the correct trust decisions and so that automated connections later don't prompt?

Comment: @Damien I'd be fine with it coming back to the foreground so I could answer the prompt.